# Server side pagination using MVC with thousands of records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently debugging the system becauae it seems to load all the data. My system has a 4200 records. Options such as serverSize and processing in Ajax are enabled but it is still not working. I want to make this faster.

This is the entity class:

```
public List<NonconformingServiceModel> GetAllNSIssue(int UserID)
    {
        using (SIRManagementSystemEntities _entities = new SIRManagementSystemEntities())
        {
            NonconformingServiceModel NSModel = new NonconformingServiceModel();
            var date1 = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
            List<NonconformingServiceModel> result = new List<NonconformingServiceModel>();

            var userData = (from _user in _entities.Administrators where _user.UserID == UserID select _user).FirstOrDefault();

            if (userData != null)
            {
                if (userData.UserType == 1 || userData.UserType == 0 || userData.UserID == 38)
                {
                    result = (from _NSDetails in _entities.NonconformingServices
                              join _creator in _entities.Administrators on _NSDetails.CreatedBy equals _creator.UserID
                              join _SIRDetails in _entities.SIR_InitialDetail on _NSDetails.NS_ID equals _SIRDetails.NSCCRefID into _sir
                              from _SIRDetails in _sir.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select new NonconformingServiceModel
                              {
                                  ID = _NSDetails.NS_ID,
                                  Type = _NSDetails.Type,
                                  Category = _NSDetails.Category,
                                  Reason = _NSDetails.Reason,
                                  Remarks = _NSDetails.Remarks,
                                  ModeThru = _NSDetails.Mode,
                                  DateDelivered = _NSDetails.DateDelivered,
                                  LoadingDate = _NSDetails.LoadingDate,
                                  DateIssue = _NSDetails.DateIssue,
                                  Origin = _NSDetails.Origin,
                                  Destination = _NSDetails.Destination,
                                  CartonNumber = _NSDetails.CartonNumber,
                                  ShipmentNumber = _NSDetails.ShipmentNumber,
                                  ShipperName = _NSDetails.ShipperName,
                                  ConsigneeName = _NSDetails.ConsigneeName,
                                  Address = _NSDetails.Address,
                                  NSGroup = _NSDetails.NSGroup,
                                  NSCode = _NSDetails.NSCode,
                                  OtherType = _NSDetails.OtherType,
                                  CreatedByID = _NSDetails.CreatedBy,
                                  CreatedByName = _creator.FirstName + " " + _creator.LastName,
                                  SIRCode = _SIRDetails.Code == null ? "" : _SIRDetails.Code,
                                  SIRDateIssue = _SIRDetails.IssueDate == null ? date1 : _SIRDetails.IssueDate,
                                  SIRDueDate = _SIRDetails.DueDate == null ? date1 : _SIRDetails.DueDate,
                                  Status = _SIRDetails.Code == null ? 0 : _SIRDetails.Status,
                              }).ToList();

                }
                else
                {
                    result = (from _creator in _entities.Administrators
                              join _NSDetails in _entities.NonconformingServices on _creator.UserID equals _NSDetails.CreatedBy
                              join _mapping in _entities.CCNSDEPTMappings on _NSDetails.NSCode equals _mapping.NSCode
                              join _SIRDetails in _entities.SIR_InitialDetail on _NSDetails.NS_ID equals _SIRDetails.NSCCRefID into _sir
                              from _SIRDetails in _sir.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              where _creator.Department == userData.Department || _mapping.ConcernDeptID == userData.Department || _creator.Department == userData.SecondDept || _mapping.ConcernDeptID == userData.SecondDept
                              select new NonconformingServiceModel
                              {
                                  ID = _NSDetails.NS_ID,
                                  Type = _NSDetails.Type,
                                  Category = _NSDetails.Category,
                                  Reason = _NSDetails.Reason,
                                  Remarks = _NSDetails.Remarks,
                                  ModeThru = _NSDetails.Mode,
                                  DateDelivered = _NSDetails.DateDelivered,
                                  LoadingDate = _NSDetails.LoadingDate,
                                  DateIssue = _NSDetails.DateIssue,
                                  Origin = _NSDetails.Origin,
                                  Destination = _NSDetails.Destination,
                                  CartonNumber = _NSDetails.CartonNumber,
                                  ShipmentNumber = _NSDetails.ShipmentNumber,
                                  ShipperName = _NSDetails.ShipperName,
                                  ConsigneeName = _NSDetails.ConsigneeName,
                                  Address = _NSDetails.Address,
                                  NSGroup = _NSDetails.NSGroup,
                                  NSCode = _NSDetails.NSCode,
                                  OtherType = _NSDetails.OtherType,
                                  CreatedByID = _NSDetails.CreatedBy,
                                  CreatedByName = _creator.FirstName + " " + _creator.LastName,
                                  SIRCode = _SIRDetails.Code == null ? "" : _SIRDetails.Code,
                                  SIRDateIssue = _SIRDetails.IssueDate == null ? date1 : _SIRDetails.IssueDate,
                                  SIRDueDate = _SIRDetails.DueDate == null ? date1 : _SIRDetails.DueDate,
                                  Status = _SIRDetails.Code == null ? 0 : _SIRDetails.Status,
                              }).ToList();

                    result = result.GroupBy(x => x.NSCode).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
                }
```

This is the view model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SIMS.Model.Models
{
    public class NonconformingServiceModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public byte Type { get; set; }
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
        public string OtherType { get; set; }
        public byte Category { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string OtherCategory { get; set; }
        public string Reason { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
        public string ModeThru { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateDelivered { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LoadingDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateIssue { get; set; }
        public string ConcernedDeptString { get; set; }
        public List<int> ConcernedDeptArray { get; set; }
        public List<string> ConcernedDeptName { get; set; }
        public string Origin { get; set; }
        public string Destination { get; set; }
        public string CartonNumber { get; set; }
        public string ShipmentNumber { get; set; }
        public string ShipperName { get; set; }
        public string ConsigneeName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string NSGroup { get; set; }
        public int CreatedByID { get; set; }
        public string CreatedByName { get; set; }
        public int CreatedByDept { get; set; }
        public int UserType { get; set; }
        public string NSCode { get; set; }
        public byte? Status { get; set; }
        public int? SIRID { get; set; }
        public string SIRCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SIRDateIssue { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SIRDueDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SubmissionDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CEDueDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DetectionDate { get; set; }
        public string FormatIssueDate { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public int? Company { get; set; }
    }

    public class FilterModel
    {
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public byte? Type { get; set; }
        public byte? Category { get; set; }
        public byte? Department { get; set; }
        public byte? Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the Controller class:

```
        {
            JsonResult _json = new JsonResult();
            NonconformingServiceManager _NSManager = new NonconformingServiceManager();
            _json.Data = _NSManager.GetAllNSIssue(UserID);
            _json.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
            return _json;
        }
```

And this is the View:

```
<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">

    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/Home/Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Nonconforming Service</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>

    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Nonconforming Services Log</h6>
            <div class="text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="window.location.reload();">Show All Data</button>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal-filter-table" class="btn btn-outline-info"><i class="fas fa-filter"></i>Sort by</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="CreateNewConcern()" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><i class="far fa-plus-square"></i> Create New NS</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-body table-responsive">
                <table id="NonconformingServiceLogGrid" class="table table-hover" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date Created</th>
                            <th>NS Code</th>
                            <th>SIR Code</th>
                            <th>Date Issue</th>
                            <th>Due Date</th>
                            <th>Submission Date</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Concerned Dept.</th>
                            <th>SIR Status</th>
                            <th>CE Due Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date Created</th>
                            <th>NS Code</th>
                            <th>SIR Code</th>
                            <th>Date Issue</th>
                            <th>Due Date</th>
                            <th>Submission Date</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Concerned Dept.</th>
                            <th>SIR Status</th>
                            <th>CE Due Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can use linq take and skip for reading records page by page, see [link](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-paging/).

Comment: If code is loading all the data than you are running the IF query with no WHERE.  So something is wrong with the testing of userType 0,1,38.  Where is userType coming from?  Is it an integer or string in the database?  If statement is testing for integer.  Should test be "1", "0", "38" with double quotes using strings?  Should you parameterize the values?

Comment: The short answer is to replace `.ToList()` with `.Skip( offset ).Take( pageSize ).ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

When using Entity Framework you need to keep in mind that a call to `ToList()` and similar methods executes the query against the database. The two large queries contain several joins and only one of them contains a `Where` condition that reduces the amount of data that is transferred from the server to the client. Especially in the first branch, the complete result of the joins is transferred resulting in a severe performance hit.

In order to reduce this, you should remove the `ToList` statements in the branches of the `if` statements and only keep the one after the grouping. This also means that you have to change the type of the `result` variable from `List<T>` to `IQueryable<T>`:

```
IQueryable<NonconformingServiceModel> result = new List<NonconformingServiceModel>()
  .AsQueryable();
// ...
result = result
  .GroupBy(x => x.NSCode)
  .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
  .ToList()
  .AsQueryable();
```

This will reduce the amount of data that is transferred to the result of the group. In addition, you can use `Skip()` and `Take()` to move the paging logic to the server and return only a single page:

```
result = result
  .GroupBy(x => x.NSCode)
  .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
  .Skip(offset)
  .Take(pageSize)
  .ToList()
  .AsQueryable();
```

In the sample above, `offset` denotes the number of rows to skip, e.g. if you are on page 4 and you have a page size of 10, you'd skip `(page - 1) * pageSize = 30` rows and take 10 rows.

If your method returns a `List<T>`, you can call `ToList()` again on the `IQueryable<T>()` so that the data that by then resides in memory is converted to a list.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I followed your suggestions but I got one error here:
IQueryable<NonconformingServiceModel> result = new List<NonconformingServiceModel>();

It says that it cannot implicitly convert type system collections generic list to system linq iqueryable.

Comment: I've added an `AsQueryable()` when creating the list

Answer (score 1):

Just make the changes in your query as per below code. It will help you to fetch the number of records as per your requirement.

Make sure you are supply the pageNumber and pageSize from UI

```
public List<NonconformingServiceModel> GetAllNSIssue(int UserID,int pageNumber=1, int pageSize=1000)
    {
        using (SIRManagementSystemEntities _entities = new SIRManagementSystemEntities())
        {
            NonconformingServiceModel NSModel = new NonconformingServiceModel();
            var date1 = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
            List<NonconformingServiceModel> result = new List<NonconformingServiceModel>();

            var userData = (from _user in _entities.Administrators where _user.UserID == UserID select _user).FirstOrDefault();

            if (userData != null)
            {
                if (userData.UserType == 1 || userData.UserType == 0 || userData.UserID == 38)
                {
                    result = (from _NSDetails in _entities.NonconformingServices
                              join _creator in _entities.Administrators on _NSDetails.CreatedBy equals _creator.UserID
                              join _SIRDetails in _entities.SIR_InitialDetail on _NSDetails.NS_ID equals _SIRDetails.NSCCRefID into _sir
                              from _SIRDetails in _sir.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select new NonconformingServiceModel
                              {
                                  ID = _NSDetails.NS_ID,
                                  Type = _NSDetails.Type,
                                  Category = _NSDetails.Category,
                                  Reason = _NSDetails.Reason,
                                  Remarks = _NSDetails.Remarks,
                                  ModeThru = _NSDetails.Mode,
                                  DateDelivered = _NSDetails.DateDelivered,
                                  LoadingDate = _NSDetails.LoadingDate,
                                  DateIssue = _NSDetails.DateIssue,
                                  Origin = _NSDetails.Origin,
                                  Destination = _NSDetails.Destination,
                                  CartonNumber = _NSDetails.CartonNumber,
                                  ShipmentNumber = _NSDetails.ShipmentNumber,
                                  ShipperName = _NSDetails.ShipperName,
                                  ConsigneeName = _NSDetails.ConsigneeName,
                                  Address = _NSDetails.Address,
                                  NSGroup = _NSDetails.NSGroup,
                                  NSCode = _NSDetails.NSCode,
                                  OtherType = _NSDetails.OtherType,
                                  CreatedByID = _NSDetails.CreatedBy,
                                  CreatedByName = _creator.FirstName + " " + _creator.LastName,
                                  SIRCode = _SIRDetails.Code == null ? "" : _SIRDetails.Code,
                                  SIRDateIssue = _SIRDetails.IssueDate == null ? date1 : _SIRDetails.IssueDate,
                                  SIRDueDate = _SIRDetails.DueDate == null ? date1 : _SIRDetails.DueDate,
                                  Status = _SIRDetails.Code == null ? 0 : _SIRDetails.Status,
                              }).Skip((pageSize*(pageNumber-1))).Take(pageSize).ToList();

                }
                else
                {
                    result = (from _creator in _entities.Administrators
                              join _NSDetails in _entities.NonconformingServices on _creator.UserID equals _NSDetails.CreatedBy
                              join _mapping in _entities.CCNSDEPTMappings on _NSDetails.NSCode equals _mapping.NSCode
                              join _SIRDetails in _entities.SIR_InitialDetail on _NSDetails.NS_ID equals _SIRDetails.NSCCRefID into _sir
                              from _SIRDetails in _sir.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              where _creator.Department == userData.Department || _mapping.ConcernDeptID == userData.Department || _creator.Department == userData.SecondDept || _mapping.ConcernDeptID == userData.SecondDept
                              select new NonconformingServiceModel
                              {
                                  ID = _NSDetails.NS_ID,
                                  Type = _NSDetails.Type,
                                  Category = _NSDetails.Category,
                                  Reason = _NSDetails.Reason,
                                  Remarks = _NSDetails.Remarks,
                                  ModeThru = _NSDetails.Mode,
                                  DateDelivered = _NSDetails.DateDelivered,
                                  LoadingDate = _NSDetails.LoadingDate,
                                  DateIssue = _NSDetails.DateIssue,
                                  Origin = _NSDetails.Origin,
                                  Destination = _NSDetails.Destination,
                                  CartonNumber = _NSDetails.CartonNumber,
                                  ShipmentNumber = _NSDetails.ShipmentNumber,
                                  ShipperName = _NSDetails.ShipperName,
                                  ConsigneeName = _NSDetails.ConsigneeName,
                                  Address = _NSDetails.Address,
                                  NSGroup = _NSDetails.NSGroup,
                                  NSCode = _NSDetails.NSCode,
                                  OtherType = _NSDetails.OtherType,
                                  CreatedByID = _NSDetails.CreatedBy,
                                  CreatedByName = _creator.FirstName + " " + _creator.LastName,
                                  SIRCode = _SIRDetails.Code == null ? "" : _SIRDetails.Code,
                                  SIRDateIssue = _SIRDetails.IssueDate == null ? date1 : _SIRDetails.IssueDate,
                                  SIRDueDate = _SIRDetails.DueDate == null ? date1 : _SIRDetails.DueDate,
                                  Status = _SIRDetails.Code == null ? 0 : _SIRDetails.Status,
                              }).ToList();

                    result = result.GroupBy(x => x.NSCode).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).Skip((pageSize*(pageNumber-1))).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                }
```